# OpenCV - Removing the independent short line in an image

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, line

How do I remove the short and disconnected line but retain all the other connected lines in the following image?

[image: There is an independent short line in top right corner image]

Comment: How about using morphological operations to look for junctions and then discarding lines which do not have junctions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you image is always this well connected, you can select the components based on their size. My code in Python (might be a simpler way, but that's how I do it) :

```
#get all connected components in the image with their stats (including their size, in pixel)
nb_edges, output, stats, _ = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img, connectivity=8) 
#output is an image where every component has a different value    
size=stats[1:,-1] #extracting the size from the statistics

#selecting bigger components
for e in range(0,nb_edges-1):
    #replace this line depending on your application, here I chose to keep
    #all components above the mean size of components in the image
    if size[e]>=np.mean(size):
        th_up = e + 2
        th_do = th_up

        #masking to keep only the components which meet the condition
        mask = cv2.inRange(output, th_do, th_up)
        result = cv2.bitwise_xor(original_img, mask)
```

Comment: Thank you! But could you please change it to C++. Python has some error with opencv3. And I also not familar with Python. Sorry

Comment: Connected components is the best way to go. @BryanYU pls don't expect people to write explicit code for you. There is ample documentation  available to convert Python to C++ and vice-versa

Comment: Thank you for your proposal.